# compound conditions in php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

The compound conditional statements doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

{{if (parseInt(address) >= 6001 && parseInt(address) <= 31999) || 
     (parseInt(address) >= 35004 && parseInt(address) <= 38589) }} 
 
          <span>Some text here....</span> 
 
          <span>Another some text here...</span> 
 
{{/if}}

```
{{if (parseInt(address) >= 6001 && parseInt(address) <= 31999) ||
    (parseInt(address) >= 35004 && parseInt(address) <= 38589) }}
    <span>Some text here...</span>;
    <span>Another some text here...</span>;
{{/if}}
```

Comment: That's not PHP, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Looks like some species of templating: Smarty? Twig?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language this is but you may be missing parens in the beginning:

**Edit:**

```
{{if((parseInt(address) >= 6001 && parseInt(address) <= 31999) || 
     (parseInt(address) >= 35004 && parseInt(address) <= 38589)) }}
          <span>Some text here....</span> 
          <span>Another some text here...</span> 
{{/if}}
```

Here is a more indented version of this code so that you can see wher perens were needed (be careful that this format may not be compatible with your language):

```
{{
    if( 
            (parseInt(address) >= 6001 && parseInt(address) <= 31999 )
                || 
            (parseInt(address) >= 35004 && parseInt(address) <= 38589)
        )
}} 
          <span>Some text here....</span> 
          <span>Another some text here...</span> 
{{
    /if
}}
```

The 2 conditions on either side of the `||` were not properly enclosed.

Comment: And for the curious among us, what language/templating system is it?

Comment: It looks a lot like Twig, as far as I can tell (I've only used Smarty).